# Excel MID function

Tags: microsoft-excel

What formula can I use to extract variable length strings, where all I know is the beginning and end points of the string. So for example, I have a large list of transactions where I need to extract the text between the "*", which are different lengths and sometimes different characters. (examples below)

```
REMARK=TRN*1*3107979027*000000000
REMARK=TRN*1*7037/09-10-19*0000000
REMARK=TRN*1*001270017788519*0000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use Text to Column from the data tab

Answer (score 0):

`Text to Column` is a good choice, but if you want to use formula to get the result, try these formulas:

**B1:** `=LEFT(A1,FIND("*",A1)-1)`
[image]

**C1:** `=MID(A1,FIND("*",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-1)`
[image]

**D1:** `=MID(A1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)+1)-FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-1)`
[image]

**E1:** `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)+1))`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Considering the sample data, to extract text between `*` sign, you need to do the following:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put text position in cell `L54 & M54`.
- Formula in Cell `L55`, fill it across.

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("*" & $J55&REPT(" ",6),"*",REPT(",",255)),L$54*255,255),",","")
  ```

---

- **Key feature** of the formula is `L$54*255`, formula reads it like `2*255` then `3*255`, where `2 & 3` are the text position between `*`
  sign.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each string is similar to what you show, with 3 substrings that are between asterisks `*`, try in some cell:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*",REPT(" ",99)),{99,198,297},99)),COLUMNS($A:A))
```

And fill right two more columns.  Then select the three columns and fill down as far as necessary.

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]