# Split string based on delimiter - #value error

Tags: microsoft-excel

My string is separated by an indefinite and variable number of underscores. "SOMETEXT_MORETEXT_ABCD_DEF_..."
I need to put each word inside a different column. I've found these links which explain exactly what I'm trying to do.

- [How to split a string based on “:” in MS-Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/483419/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-in-ms-excel)
- [Split text into different columns from the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349415/split-text-into-different-columns-from-the-right/43349766)
- [How To Reverse The Concatenate Function In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3278-excel-reverse-concatenate.html)

The formula is `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))`

I've used the exact same formula and changed the references and the delimiter but it doesn't work and gives me a #value error.

My file: https://app.box.com/s/q21pc0r04sqvf4ewdjw6b1cmtu6o0cnn

I don't understand why there's this error. Can anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: Use text to columns. It is found in the data tab.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I can't do that because it requires the user's input at some point. It needs to be automated because the file will be fed to a software eventually.

Comment: @ScottCraner you can find the example I'm working with at the link above (on box.com)

Comment: @ScottCraner A1 is "WORD,RED,ORANGE,RULER" and B1 is =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1;",";REPT(" ";999));COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998;999)). There's a ; because I'm using a non-US version of excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow, this is so strange, I keep getting the same error instead. May I ask you if you could upload your excel file somewhere so I can have a look and play with it?

Comment: I downloaded yours and when it translated the formula you were using AVERAGE not MID.  I am not sure what language you are using but it seems as if you mistranslated MID to the wrong function in your language.

Comment: You should be using `STRINGA.ESTRAI` not `MEDIA`

Comment: @scottcraner Duh! You're right. I got it from a website that listed a wrong translation. If you want to change your comment to an answer I'm going to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Nah, was a typo.  Glad to have helped.

Comment: @Barbara,, [check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1481591/excel-mid-function/1481774#1481774) recently I've solved almost the same issue,, in used formula you need to  replace `*` with `_` only and it work for you.

Comment: @RajeshS thank you! As Scott explained it was actually a mistranslation (see comment 7). I'm using a non-US version of excel, I got the translation of MID from https://www.excel-function-translation.com/ but it was wrong.

Comment: Solved. See [Scott's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1481917/split-string-based-on-delimiter-value-error?noredirect=1#comment2235141_1481917). Thank you @scottCraner.